# Sum of Sequence Involving Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a sequence with explicit formula $b_n = F_{n+4} -(n+3)$ The question asks me to use that formula to hence find the following sum for each $n$:
$$nF_1 + (n-1)F_{2} +(n-2)F_3 +...+2F_{n-1}+F_n $$
I feel like the answer to my question will be very obvious, but I really don't know where to start with it.

Comment: Is the sum equal to $b_n$? If so, you can probably prove it using induction.

Comment: I have that $b_n = F_{n+4} - (n+3)$ which can be changed to $b_n = 2F_n +3F_{n+1} - (n+3)$. But I don't think I can get that strictly in terms of $b_n$.

Comment: @NicoMonk: Induction works to prove that $nF_1+(n-1)F_2+\cdots +F_n=F_{n+4}-(n+3)\ (=b_n)$. Don't you want to use induction?

Comment: @mathlove I wasn't sure if induction would work here. I am as happy to use induction as the next guy on this website. I just wasn't sure if $b_n$ could be made to equal the sum. Like I said above, the solution was probably very obvious.